# Paint made on motor cover block of my motorbike is getting blistered

Tags: motorcycle, rust, chassis-paint

What I'm trying to explain is that the paint layer is getting in a form to be peeled off easily. As far as I guess I need the peel the current paint applied and repaint it. Is this something that an amateur manage? Or do I need to go directly to a professional?

[image: Blistered paint]

Comment: Can you post any pics of the peeling? Depending on the nature and extent of the peeling that will affect the answers.

Comment: @motosubatsu Here are the pictures https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1EGqsJ0N2FowXgHJKCncMdozkeER5uyyL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things come to mind about why your paint might be blistering/peeling.
1. Was the part prepped correctly?
a. Was all the old paint removed prior to applying new paint? Old paint underneath new paint can sometimes flake of or show an uneven result.
b. Was the part gently scuffed using a 3M pad or 400 grit sandpaper? Smooth surfaces such as chrome or polished aluminum need to be scuffed up enough to give the paint something to cling to.
c. Was the part thoroughly cleaned and degreased prior to new paint being applied? Use a proper degreaser, mild soap and water, water rinse, and possibly a tack-chloth to remove dust particles.
2. Was the part painted correctly?
a. Was the paint used a paint designated for use on engines? High heat and used for metal surfaces.
b. Did the paint manufacturer recommend using a primer before painting?
c. If a primer paint was used was it made by the same manufacturer? Sometimes different brands of paints/primers can have a chemical reaction which can result in dimpling, orange peeling, or blistering.
d. Use of multiple light coats will produce a much better result than heavy coats. Also important is to allow the paint to dry between layers.
3. Did the part get sealed with a clear-coat once the paint was thoroughly dry?

Additional thoughts I have is to ask if you've considered having the part powder-coated? It is very inexpensive and typically resists chips and cracks much better.
If you remove paint by sandblasting and the part is a soft metal like aluminum consider using baking soda instead of a sand medium.

I hope my thoughts help you get the desired results you are looking for. -R

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 main challenges here.

1. Dissembling/reassembling to get the engine side cover off and back on.
2. Stripping, prepping and painting the side cover.

From your photo it looks like there is a hydraulic clutch, and an oil sight glass, which means you will need to drain oil before you remove the side cover. When you reinstall it, it will probably need a gasket replaced.

Looking at the blistering, the old paint will need to be stripped carefully, and the metal may have some corrosion or oxidisation. Alloy is soft so you cant use grinders or hard wire brush wheels as they will leave scratches. I have had really good results it the past with sand blasting. Paintstripper, heat guns or acid dipping may work but can be risky. You need to be careful with sight-glass and sealing surfaces.

Once its prepped it will need to be painted with a suitable engine high temperature paint. Ive done this with spray cans, but you might want to ask an auto painter what they would charge.

I am a self taught amatuer and have done jobs like this. But you have to ask yourself if you are comfortable giving it a go. You dont have to do it all your self. You could ask a mechanic to remove/reinstall and you could do the painting, or you could remove it get a painter to help if you're unsure about that.

Another option is to buy a 2nd hand side cover and swap them. That will get your bike back on the road the quickest, and if you still want to restore this one it wont matter so much if you damage it or mess it up.